# Вывод определенного пользователя.

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Всем привет, я вывожу из базы все данные определенного пользователя, но мне выдает ошибку.

Вот такой вот скрипт.

Мне надо, чтоб выводилось из двух строк. Из **im** и **senderID**

```
$myID = $userinfo["id"];
if(isset($_GET['im']))
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE im='$_GET[im]', senderID='$myID'") or die("Ошибочный запрос к БД".mysql_error());
```

При этом запросе выдает ошибку.

```
Ошибочный запрос к БДYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE senderID='1'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. между im и senderID нужно ставить не запятую, а AND
2. судя по тексту ошибки запрос не такой, как вы написали здесь, сообщается что перед WHERE senderID ошибка в запросе
3. расширением mysql давно рекомендуется не пользоваться, начиная с версии 5.5 оно deprecated (пользуйтесь MySQLi или PDO)
4. всегда проверяйте данные, приходящие с клиента, у вас там SQL инъекция так и просится
5. не пользуйтесь die(), в PHP есть механизм обработки исключений для таких ситуаций